# Chess software for writing books

Tags: learning, software, books

I am currently converting some of my chess books into electronic format by manually copying the pgn and making notes. I have found lichess study and chessable courses to be useful in doing this. However, I would like to do this offline. Is there a software which will do this for me? I am looking at ChessX but the interface is too complicated for me to even understand if this is what I want.

Comment: Is your question about converting a PDF or physical copy into an annotated PGN file?

Answer (score 5):

If you're familiar with [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) (or if you're willing to learn it, which in my opinion is time well spent), there are some user-created packages which exist just for that. These are very easy to download (e.g. via with the [MiKTeX Package Manager](https://miktex.org/)) and use.

To my knowledge, the most extensive and well-documented of these packages for creating chessboards is [chessboard](https://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard). As you can see in the documentation, it's highly flexible. As for chess fonts (i.e. being able to write moves with the symbol for the piece rather than the letter for the piece), there's the package [chessfss](https://ctan.org/pkg/chessfss). There are other packages too if ever these aren't to your liking, for example [chess-problem-diagrams](https://ctan.org/pkg/chess-problem-diagrams).

Comment: I use LaTeX for my research, so I use it frequently. However, my question is different. I would like to have the book in an interactive sense, i.e., something like the http://andrewphoy.github.io/chess-replayer/ embedded.